# Rank of a subtraction of matrix: equality vs inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there any cases in which the following inequality
$$ 
\mathrm{rank}\left(A-B\right) \geq \lvert \mathrm{rank}(A) - \mathrm{rank}(B) \rvert.
$$

converts into a equality? For some matrices, like
$$
H = \mathbf{I} - \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\mathbf{1} = \left(1,1,\ldots,1\right)^T$, it follows that $\mathrm{rank}\left(H\right) = n-1$.

Another way to see it is if there are cases in which the inequality $\geq$ converts into $>$.